# CommonJS require() or ES6 import/export in nodejs production?

Tags: node.js, module

I have got the latest version of npm modules and developing a nodejs application. The problem is that some npm modules support the `require()` and the others support the `import/export` statements, I cannot use them both in a file.

Having the production criteria in mind, which should I opt for either only require() or only import/export or a mix of those using the dynamic import() along with the require(). Thanks

Comment: That depends on your Node.js version and if your package is defined as ESM or CommonJS package. See https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type
Are you using JavaScript or TypeScript?

Comment: Hi @zirkelc, I m using javascript. How to find whether a npm module is deined as ESM or CommonJS ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: The package.json defines a `type` field with either `module` for ESM or `commonjs` for CommonJS.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are talking about plain JavaScript without transpiling from TypeScript or Babel.

The `require()` function is used to load CommonJS modules whereas the `import` statement is used to load ESM modules. Which of them you should or can use depends on factors such as:

- does your target Node.js version support ESM? I think ESM in Nodejs support got introduced in v12, but I'm not sure how stable it is.
- is your package defined as ESM or CommonJS module. That depends on the **type** field in your **package.json**, with `"type": "module"` for ESM and `"type": "commonjs"` for CommonJS: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type
- are your package dependencies provided as ESM or CommonJS modules. That depends on each individual **package.json** and their **type** field as well as if the package is provided as both ESM and CommonJS modules with conditional exports: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a definite answer for you because that depends on your environment. ESM and `import` statements are going to be the future of JS, but the ESM support in the Node.js ecosystem is not on par with CommonJS *yet*.

With this in mind, I would opt for CommonJS modules *but* I would use a transpiler like TypeScript so I can still use modern features of JS.